# Django MongoDB SITE_ID error

Tags: django, mongodb

I am getting this error when trying to view the admin page:

```
InvalidId at /admin/

AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'1' instead). Please make sure your SITE_ID contains a valid ObjectId string.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     InvalidId
Exception Value:    

AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'1' instead). Please make sure your SITE_ID contains a valid ObjectId string.
...
```

So I googled around and figured that I needed to do the following

```
 ./manage.py tellsiteid
The default site's ID is u'50c5766e62f11f41f0332e65'. To use the sites framework, add this line to settings.py:
SITE_ID=u'50c5766e62f11f41f0332e65'
```

So I added it to my `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
SITE_ID = u'50c5766e62f11f41f0332e65'
...
```

I still get that same error message. Am I supposed to run a `syncdb` or restart the server? Because I've done both and am still getting the same error.

**EDIT**

I've tried viewing the value of `SITE_ID` in the Python shell, and sure enough...

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from concepts.settings import *
>>> SITE_ID
1
```

But `git diff` clearly shows that I have changed the settings file, right?

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/settings.py b/settings.py
index 586ea3a..bb069ed 100644
--- a/settings.py
+++ b/settings.py
@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@

 DEBUG = True
 TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
+SITE_ID = u'50c5766e62f11f41f0332e65'

 ADMINS = (
     # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
 ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohhhh silly me. These lines of code appeared later in `settings.py`:

```
# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True
...
```

So I simply changed the 1 there to `u'50c5766e62f11f41f0332e65'` and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but even when I changed SITE_ID in my *settings.py* the problem remained.  I commented the line 'django.contrib.sites' in INSTALLED_APPS and syncdb finished then properly (the sites application seems to me as an application that almost nobody would need...so quick and clean solution :))